# Error: "The file could not be found" in upload file with Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to upload images in my application to store them in the database and following this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html) have the following code:

Controller:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{        
    $entity = new Student();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
       $file = $entity->getPhoto();

       $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

       $photoDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/uploads/images';

       $file->move($photoDir, $fileName);

       $entity->setPhoto($fileName);

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $em->persist($entity);
       $em->flush();

      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }
    return $this->render('BackendBundle:Student:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Entity:

```
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

   //...
   /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
   * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/png","image/jpg" })
   */
   private $photo;


   public function setPhoto($photo)
   {
    $this->photo = $photo;

    return $this;
   }

   public function getPhoto()
   {
    return $this->photo;
   }
```

formtype:

```
   //...

   ->add('photo', 'file', array('required' => false))

   //...
```

With this code I get the error message:"The file could not be found", and I do not know how to fix it to save files uploaded.

Update: I think the mistake is in the ajax request I make before, which does not send the file correctly field. How could this type of field to send correctly by ajax?  I have shown the value that sends the Ajax request in this field and is "on", so I think that's the problem.

---

**Solution**: I've solved changing in my code:

- `data: new FormData($(this)[0])` instead of `data: $ (this).serialize()`
- Adding the ajax request:

  `processData: false,`
    `contentType: false,`
    `cache: false,`

and the file is sent correctly.

Comment: Where do you get that error? Is this a validation error or a PHP error? Is it the exact error message you get?

Comment: Hi @xabbuh , It is a form validation error. I am currently doing an ajax call the submit and get back there that error message. Look at another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885497/symfony-2-3-form-this-form-should-not-contain-extra-fields-error) I posted, I followed another way and it seems that is all right but I get another error.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is sent with your AJAX call? Does it work when you do not submit the form through AJAX requests? By the way, you will hardly get the right answers if you constantly change your code and post new questions with the changed code while the old question still wasn't answered.

Comment: Hi @xabbuh  ,sorry  I made the different questions as I go along because other codes for the same problem and I get other error messages thought the same and helped see the solution. Now I'm trying the other code and the message still does not make an Ajax request, symfony displays alvalidar the form.

Comment: Hi @xabbuh, Miraculously, I tested the form without Ajax request Symfony as you told me and showed me the following:

`Unable to write in the "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/../web/uploads/images" directory`

From what I have seen that the error was due to permit problems in the target directory. Thank you very much for your dedication.

Comment: Hello again @xabbuh, Without the Ajax request everything is stored correctly, but when I do the Ajax request now I get this error 500: `Error: Call to a member function guessExtension() on a non-object in /opt
/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/src/School/StudentBundle/Controller/StudentController.php line 135`.Would you know why that is?

Comment: Hi @xabbuh, by testing I think the error is in the ajax request I make before, which does not send the file correctly field. How could this type of field to send correctly by ajax?Because without the Ajax request it is perfectly done, but I need to send it by ajax.  I have shown the value that sends the Ajax request in this field and is "on", so I think that's the problem.

Comment: Hi @xabbuh, at the end I just fix my code changing `data: $ (this) .serialize ()` with `data: new FormData ($ (this) [0])`

Answer (score 0):

Joseph

You are miss some code like:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Your request data not bind with entity that's why got error. Please check again link which you are given

Comment: Hi @AshokChitroda , the code that you say I have added, there have only put some code that relates to upload files.

Comment: Well, it's hard to help you if the code in your question doesn't reflect that. Please update your question with the code as it actually is.

Comment: Hi @xabbuh, I've updated the code. By the way, when I changed my code following the official document, then run `app / console doctrine: schema: update --force`
. With that the tables in the database would be updated and should work all right? Or is there something else to do to update my code above?